# Making changes to multiple copies of the same file in a repository

Tags: github

I'm new to github and have created a repository with multiple folders. Each folder has a copy of the same file (say abc.txt). I've linked my account to github desktop, so I have a matching local repository.

I constantly make changes to abc.txt in one of my local folders, but I want to push that change on to ALL copies of abc.txt in my online repository. The obvious alternative is to just copy and replace all copies of abc.txt on my local machine by the latest version, and push my entire local repository online, but surely there's a better way?

Comment: Why would you want multiple copies of the same file in the same repo? Why not just copy it wherever your need during the deployment process?

Comment: Because the repository has multiple projects. Each project requires that file. Ideally I'd want to make changes to abc.txt in one project, and next time I'm working on the same file in another project, I want to start with the updated version of that file.

Comment: That sounds like an odd way to do that. Why not have a base repo with the file and each project can have its own repo using the base repo as a submodule?

Comment: I agree, but each project is so small that dedicating an entire repo to each of them would be overkill. So I've settled for just dividing them into folders. The projects are small because I'm currently learning C++ and how to maintain a github repository.